# How to build a digital distribution platform for games like Steam

Tags: steam, software-distribution

I would like to know how do i start building a Digital Distribution Platform like Steam, where do i start?

I'm interested in designing a platform for indie games, where gamers can make purchases from my website.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to be rude, but there are hundreds of these platforms in the web... and noone uses them.

...do you have the know-how to start this. Do you know how to write code which can distribute data, can store vlaues in databases, etc? Do you have a team (you can not do this on your own)

If yes, i recommend writing a very detailled plan first.